# Am I using noConflict() properly?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-typeahead

What I am trying to accomplish:

The version of jquery legacy code is using is 1.2.6. I want to use Typeahead by twitter which requires 1.9+. So noConflict would be the first choice to go. I import 1.2.6(it supports $.browser.msie), get the browser type. import 1.9 and twitter Typeahead. I do noConflict to return to 1.2.6 and assign noConflict to some variable.

The code(in jsp page):

```
    <ps:script src="/jquery/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" />
    <ps:script src="/jquery/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js" />
    <ps:script src="/mustache/mustache.js" />

    <script src="/autosuggest/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/autosuggest/bootstrap-2.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     var jq191 = $.noConflict(true);
     // jquery 1.9 does not support $.browser.msie, so do ie check first then pass it to autosuggest
     var ie = false;
            if ($.browser.msie) { ie = true; }

            jq191(function() {
                var url = "<%= System.getProperty("url") %>";
                var autoSuggest = new AutoSuggest(url, [
                    {inputId: "input1", buttonId: "input1button", destination: "dest1"},
                    {inputId: "input2", buttonId: "input2button", destination: "dest2"}
                ], ie);
                autoSuggest.config();
            });
        </script>
```

config() is method to configure stuff for Typeahead and etc.

So far on firefox and chrome, everything works great. On IE it randomly throws this "SCRIPT 428" error(literally random, I only see this error after refreshing/opening pages for 10-20 times.

Is my usage of noConflict() correct? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are using `noConflict()` correctly. I don't see anything wrong other than the usage of jQuery 1.2.6 and `$.browser`.

Comment: Using jquery 1.2.6 just to support `$.browser.msie` it's what is not 'correct'

Comment: @KevinB then why does stupid ie keep throwing that damn error..

Comment: @roasted 1.2.6 is what the legacy code uses so i cannot change that.

Comment: Upgrade to latest version of jQuery, then include jQuery migrate to restore functionality that has been removed.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy its really big app, im not sure how big the change is.

Comment: what version of IE is it happening in? All of them?

Comment: @KevinB so far, ie8 and ie9 where ie8 is the majority of the users.